# iOS 5 Developer Transition Guide?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4, ios5

Is there any guide for developers explaining how they can prepare their application to be iOS5 compatible?  I have searched around but haven't been able to find anything yet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing I see is this checklist:

http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/checklist/

An excerpt: "Existing apps in the App Store and those built using iOS 4 SDK should already run on iOS 5 without modification. However, you should test your existing apps running iOS 5 to be certain there aren’t any compatibility issues. iOS 5 works with iPad 2, iPad, iPhone 4, iPhone 3GS, and the third and fourth-generation iPod touch."